# How to clear the android downloadmanager notification?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-download-manager

I am downloading a zip file from the server using DownloadManager. After downloading I extracted the content from the file and showed in my app.

I want to clear the Download Complete Notification programmatically so that I can generate a new notification of "File is Extracting" like Play Store does and after extraction is complete, will show the new notification showing the "Extraction Completed".

I have attached the screenshots of the play store notification.

When file is installing [image]

When file installed [image]

Comment: Nobody has the answer ? It's possible to use remove(id), but this remove also the file downloaded, and it's necessary to save it before... not very clean to clear the notification (and keep the file of course) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set this to your request:

```
 request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
```